# How to insert a column of ones and zeros into a matrix using Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix with a set of integers. I want to use the check `rand > 0.5` to prepend a random vector of 1s and 0s to my matrix. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a 6x1 matrix but you should get the point.

```
octave:1> a = [7;8;2;3;6;7];
octave:2> a = [a, rand(size(a))>0.5]
a =

   7   0
   8   1
   2   1
   3   0
   6   1
   7   0
```